# can i show a complete html page(tags,elements) in the typescript or console?

Tags: angular2-template

I want to get the html of a page into console like when the page loads whole html must be shown in the console.log.
Is it possible to do this in Angular 2.

Answer (score 1):

Angular only boostraps the app-root tag which has all of the sub modules and components in it. You can use Augury to inspect the html of your angular projects. Augury is a Google Chrome Dev Tool extension for debugging and visualizing Angular applications at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Bolanle Bincom, But can i store my html in the variable when the page loads through this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you would want to, but you can get the entire body's HTML into the console like this...

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(document.body); // The browser will let you navigate the body's DOM like this
    console.log(document.body.innerHTML); // Or this will just render it as a giant string
    console.log(document.documentElement.outerHTML); // Or you might want the entire HTML document, including the <html> and <head> and <body> etc.
}
```